# SwiftUI: Update view on element property of an array changes

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I wanted to show a list of tags that can be selectable and want to make sure only one tag is selected in the list.

I tried to use `@State`, `@ObservedObject`, and `@Published`, but no luck. What is the best solution here?

```
import SwiftUI

struct Tag: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    var selected: Bool = false
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var tags: [Tag]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(tags) { tag in
                TagView(name: tag.name, isSelected: tag.selected) {
                    for (index, _) in tags.enumerated() {
                        // select only one tag
                        tags[index].selected = tags[index].id == tag.id
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TagView: View {
    let name: String
    @State var isSelected: Bool
    var onAction: (() -> Void) = { }
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: onAction) {
            Text(name)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding()
                .background(
                    isSelected ? Color.red : Color.blue
                )
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(tags: [
            Tag(id: 1, name: "Swift"),
            Tag(id: 2, name: "Xcode"),
            Tag(id: 3, name: "Apple")
        ])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `@State` of `isSelected` variable in TagView resolved the issue